# Unable to include Antlr4 as dependency in OSGI bundle

Tags: java, osgi

I am adding the following dependency to my OSGI bundle:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
    <artifactId>antlr4</artifactId>
    <version>4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

But I am getting the following error when I include mycom.myProject.Antlr.* in `<Private-Package>`:

> ERROR: Bundle mycom.myProject.BundleFile [241] Error starting
>   file:/C:/username/apache-servicemix-7.0.0.M2/deploy/BundleFile-1.0.0.jar
>   (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to resolve
>   mycom.myProject.BundleFile   [241](R 241.76): missing requirement
>   [mycom.myProject.BundleFile [241](R 241.76)] osgi.wiring.package;
>   (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.antlr.v4.runtime)(version>=4.7.0)(!(version>=5.0.0)))
>   Unresolved requirements:   [[mycom.myProject.BundleFile [241](R
>   241.76)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.antlr.v4.runtime)(version>=4.7.0)(!(version >=5.0.0)))])

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Can you share your manifest.mf file ?

Comment: `Bundle-Name: MyProject::BundleFile  
Bundle-SymbolicName: mycom.MyProject.BundleFile  
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0  
BundleType: MyProject  
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin  
Import-Package: android.util,javax.jms;version="[1.1,2)",javax.net,javax
 .net.ssl,javax.security.auth.x500,org.antlr.v4.runtime;version="[4.7,5)
 ",org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn;version="[4.7,5)",org.antlr.v4.runtime.dfa;v
 ersion="[4.7,5)",org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree;version="[4.7,5)",org.apache
 .activemq;version="[5.7,6)",org.apache.camel.osgi,org.osgi.framework;ve
 rsion="[1.8,2)"
Tool: Bnd-1.50.0`

Answer (score 0):

If I read correctly your log, OSGI want an antlr version >= 4.7.0. But there is only a 4.7 version.

Try to change all the version entry in your manifest.mf for antlr to something like:

```
version="4.7",
```

Also, there is space between the end of the version and the ". Maybe try

`org.antlr.v4.runtime;versi‌​on="[4.7,5)"` instead of

```
org.antlr.v4.runtime;versi‌​on="[4.7,5) "
```

Comment: antlr 4 is missing, cuz I have not provided it in my project? How can I include antlr4 alongside my own bundle?

Comment: <Export-Package>mycom.myProject.myBundle.Manager.*,org.antlr.*</Export-Package>